# Playwright - how to find input that will contain a value?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I have an Input element with value like '123 456'.

How can I validate that the Input element contains '123' using an Expect?

```
input_locator = 'input[id="edition"]'
expect(self.page.locator(input_locator).first).
to_have_value('123', timeout=20 * 1000)
```

I got this error:

selector resolved to <input name="" readonly type="text" id="edition" placeh…/>
unexpected value "123 456"

selector resolved to <input name="" readonly type="text" id="edition" placeh…/>
unexpected value "123 456"

Comment: Did you try [to_contain_text](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-contain-text)?

Comment: @hardkoded Hey. No, it does not work. The input element has no exposed text attribute, only input value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_have_value` supports regular expressions. You can do something like this:

```
expect(self.page.locator(input_locator).first).
to_have_value(re.compile(r"123.+"), timeout=20 * 1000)
```

Comment: Correction, it's re.compile("123")